# has anybody re-entered the USA on the VWP, and how long was the time in between entries?

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

I know to re-enter the USA you are required to leave the continent and neighbouring islands. I plan to go to the USA at the end of May, stay for up to 90 days, but I would like to visit again and want to know how much time anybody has spent between visits.

Is one month enough? I will enter first with my girlfriend who is from the US, I am a British citizen, then we will leave to somewhere outside the continent, then we would like to go again for another period of time before finally leaving again to go elsewhere.

From what I can find out it appears it's totally up to the border official. I have funds to support myself for the entire duration of both stays, I will not be working, I will have onward travel plans each time, i.e. a flight out after the first visit and after the second.

Unfortunately I'm not in the UK now and won't be before I go to the US otherwise I would apply for a 6 month visa, and from what I understand, applying for a 6 month visa outside your home country reduces the chances of it being granted anyway.
So basically what are the chances of me being allowed to enter again after just 3 or 4 weeks outside the US? Or is it just a chance I'll have to take? And anyway who would be responsible for me leaving the states if I was refused entry? I'd have to get a flight myself or the US immigration would put me on a plane somewhere? Ha, I know it's a lot but any help, or if anybody has experience of multiple entries, any advice would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Ok, clearly similar questions have been asked before, I explained the information I have already gathered from such questions and posts. It is all theoretical. What I want to known is people's actual experiences. How long HAVE people actually left for, WHERE did they go, and how were the border officials attitudes and questions asked upon re-entering?

I explained what I have already found out which you kindly marked my question as a duplicate and linked a similar question to it. But what I am after is people's personal accounts of doing this, not just how it works in theory, it is not difficult to find this information, it is however difficult out to find personal accounts!

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I don't think asking specifically for opinions is a good idea here (and you don't stress your real question anyway). In general entry in a country is subject to the custom agent will. The criteria that matter, I think, are in particular your place of residence. UK is not a country that might refuse their citizens or push them to exile. They will ask you what is your intent and it should be clearly said, without hesitation, and it should be that you visit the country. As you said, they search for illegal migrants, they don't want to scare tourists. So you got it all.

Comment: also look at that, I think it will interest you: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23622/who-pays-for-the-return-ticket-when-a-country-refuses-entry

Comment: Thanks allot for your help Vince! I'm not asking for opinions, I would like to know of anybodies actual experience with re-entering in a short time frame. I agree, I don't think I'd raise any major concerns, I just don't want to be refused entry, want to make sure I have all bases covered, and am probably over-thinking the situation anyway. Thanks again for your help and response!

Comment: And thanks for the link that is also really helpful! :-)