# Transit Visa for China for layover in Guangzhou and Wuhan

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, china, china-southern-airlines

I will be traveling to SFO from Delhi in Feb 2020.

I am an Indian citizen and I have B1/B2 Visa for the USA.

**Route:** Delhi → New Baiyun, Guangzhou (4h 05m Layover) → Wohnung (2h 00m Layover) → SFO

**Return:** SFO → Wuhan (2h 40m Layover) → New Baiyun, Guangzhou (7h 45m Layover) → Delhi

Will I need the transit visa or not?

Answer (score 2):

Your link from the Chinese embassy is not really relevant as it only mentions transit in one city without leaving the airport, which does not apply in your case.

However, China does allow 24-hour visa-free transit for most people even if travelling through multiple Chinese airports. The exact rules according to Timatic are

> Passengers with a confirmed onward air, cruise or train
>     ticket to a third country within 24 hours can obtain an
>     entry permit on arrival. They must have documents required
>     for the next destination.
>
> When passengers have obtained an entry permit, **they can have
>     multiple transit stops within China** (People's Rep.).
>
> - This TWOV facility does not apply at Shenzhen (SZX) when
>     passengers are traveling to Hong Kong (SAR China) or Macao
>     (SAR China).
> - This TWOV facility does not apply at Fuzhou (FOC),
>     Huangshan (TXN), Mudanjiang (MDG), Urumqi (URC) and Yanji
>     (YNJ).
> - This TWOV facility does not apply to nationals of Syria
>     transiting through Guangzhou (CAN).
> - This TWOV facility does not apply to nationals of
>     Afghanistan, Azerbaijan, Iran, Iraq, Kazakhstan,
>     Kyrgyzstan, Malaysia, Oman, Pakistan, Saudi Arabia, Sri
>     Lanka, Syria, Thailand, Turkey, Turkmenistan and Yemen
>     transiting through Xiamen (XMN).
> - [...]
> - This TWOV facility does not apply when
>     passengers arrive on a direct flight from USA, Guam or
>     Northern Mariana Isl. AND depart on a direct flight to USA,
>     Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. (e.g. JFK - PVG - GUM).

As none of these exceptions apply to you, you will be able to get an entry permit upon arrival and will hence not need to apply for a transit visa in advance.

[TravelChinaGuide](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-transit-24hour.htm) has some more information about how the 24-hour transit rule works.

Comment: This is counter dicted by the following http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/hzqz/zgqz/t84242.htm, now I am not sure which one is correct but I do know that the VISA free rules are very new and as such interpretation of them might vary a lot, I would highly recommend having things in order before flying to be on the safe side until this settles down some more. Even asking the Shanghai Entry and Exit department gives different answers when called 3 times to check this out.

Comment: @MattDouhan: I guess the Chinese Embassy in the US just wants more people to apply for transit visas so they earn more money? In any case, this policy has been around for a while now and there are official sources online (e. g. the [Chinese embassy in Estonia](http://ee.china-embassy.org/eng/tzygg/t1460983.htm)) confirming the 24-hour TWOV rule.

Comment: Yes but as always in China things are not always what it seems, it takes time sometimes a long time for things to settle and rules are many times interpreted different by different staff etc, like I said I called the Shanghai entry and exit department and they gave three different answers on three calls during the same day when I wanted to verify this, it is clear it should be available but your mileage may vary is all I am saying

Comment: @MattDouhan http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/hzqz/zgqz/t84242.htm this was last updated on 19/09/2008 after that Rules are changed it seems.

Comment: @Maulik Like I said I called the entry and exit department, get different answers depending on who you speak to, it should be possible but your mileage may wary

Comment: @MattDouhan another concern is, is 2h 00m Layover is enough in Wuhan?

Comment: @Maulik Tight but possible, WUHAN is not a big airport, security lines should be ok to get out pick luggage etc, but then again Murphy’s law....

Comment: @Maulik: On the outbound trip, your baggage will be checked through from CAN to SFO (remind the agent in CAN if necessary), so you only have to go through exit immigration in WUH. Two hours is more than enough for that. On the return, you'll have to collect your baggage in WUH, go through customs and re-check the baggage at the domestic counter, but there should be enough time for that as well. If not, China Southern will reaccommodate you on another flight to Delhi.

Comment: @MattDouhan: And as I said, the 24-hour transit is a well-established practice and with confirmed onward flights, there will be no reason to be denied a TWOV. Between poor call quality and and potential language issues, I would not attach much credibility to any information you received on the phone.

Comment: @Mophotla uhm I live in shanghai and speak fluent Chinese

Answer (score 0):

Taking from the currently hot question [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/150878/no-transit-zone-at-linate-airport-couldnt-get-on-connecting-flight-whose-resp), you will probably need more than a transit visum for the China leg (Wuhan/Guangzhou) because you're on a domestic flight.

Comment: Pay attention to this answer, you are on a domestic flight in mainland China, you will need a proper VISA to go on that flight, wether or not you qualify for VISA on arrival will heavily depend on your nationality but also please note I am unsure if WUHAN is one of the airports that offer that service, you better check this with the airline and/or consulate before you travel to make sure you dont get suck

Comment: @MattDouhan : But here it says 24 hr stay is visa-free http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/hzqz/zgqz/t84242.htm is it something I am wrongly referring or what ? I am not sure and confused.

Comment: @Maulik But he does not qualify for any of the two cases mentioned, the first one is not available to Indian citizens and the second one does not include WUHAN and besides he has a domestic flight leg so he is not staying in the same airport during transit

Comment: @MattDouhan: I am not talking about getting a visa on arrival, which is indeed almost impossible in China for regular tourists. I am saying that Maulik does not need a visa at all, i. e. he can transit _visa-free_. This does not depend on his nationality and Wuhan, as all other airports in China except the few ones mentioned in my answer, offer this service. The airline will not be able to help at all and will just refer the passenger to the embassy.