# If denied entry to EU, what US city do they send me to?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, airports, eu

I have read many times that they send US citizens back to the US on the first flight that is available, but which city will they send me to? Flights to some cities can be very expensive. Could the flight cost over a thousand dollars?

Comment: Why would they send you to the US?  They'd usually send you wherever you came from or where you are a citizen.

Comment: The EU is a big place, I doubt there's a uniform answer for how they decide which flight you're going back on. But could it cost over a thousand dollars? You're asking about the price of a short-notice ticket for a transatlantic flight. Yes, it could be expensive.

Comment: Related question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23622/who-pays-for-the-return-air-ticket-when-a-country-refuses-entry-by-air

Comment: For what it's worth, the IATA Ticketing Manual (linked to in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/100806/31165)) just says, "the place to which a passenger must be ticketed will be advised by the responsible authorities."

Comment: You can’t get “denied entry to the EU”. The EU is not a country. Not all EU countries’ immigration rules are the same, either. Which country are you talking about?

Comment: EDIT: I have been notified that the answer to my question is "US city of origin."

Comment: The "they" who refuse you entry, are not the "they" that have to bring you back.  I believe the latter is the airline that carried you in (which is also why fugitives have to flee by boat because the airline will not let them board).

Comment: Why the UK tag?

Comment: This is a non-issue. Airlines are obligated to haul you back, and this costs money. So they make sure you will (with reasonable certitude, barring the possibility that you call the border guard a faggot or such) not be denied **before** letting you board. The plane is going back anyway (usually serving A-B-A-B-A-B), so in case it _does happen_ that you're denied, there you go. (Edited by a mod.)

Comment: @Damon The airlines have nothing to do with making sure whether or not you'll be denied by a border guard for reasons out of the airline's control. Airlines only check your passport and plane ticket, not other things like bank statements.

Answer (score 40):

Most of the time, if you are refused entry to a country, you will be sent back to the airport from which your flight to that country departed, usually on the same airline which carried you to that country.

For instance, if your itinerary was MEX-JFK-LHR, if you were refused entry at Heathrow, you would be sent back to New York (not Mexico City).

In a few cases I've heard of, immigration officers in various countries have used their discretion to allow someone refused entry to arrange their own transportation out of the country. You should not count on this being available to you, though if the situation arises you can always ask.

Comment: What happens if you're inadmissible to the place where you connected?  This wouldn't apply to the US (there's very little TWOV there), but for example, you could conceivably transit CDG without being able to enter the Schengen area.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You either get to book your own flights to wherever, or you end up [living in the airport for 27+ years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehran_Karimi_Nasseri).

Comment: And now that planes have the range to no longer need to make fuel stops at ANC for trans-Pacific flights, there is virtually zero TWOV in the US.

Answer (score 16):

Given the EU is a large place with varying policies, I will answer based on the UK and also based on another answer here in Travel Stack Exchange where this has happened.

The question ["What are the visa rules for US speakers, at UK conferences, who may be getting paid?"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77241/what-are-the-visa-rules-for-us-speakers-at-uk-conferences-who-may-be-getting-p) which was triggered by [this blog post by Rachel Nabors](https://medium.com/@rachelnabors/wtfuk-73009d5623b4) about her experience being refused entry and removed from the UK, includes an interesting answer from long time Travel SE user and former UK immigration legal adviser [Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow).

In this particular removal, the US visitor denied entry was sent back to the US east coast (NYC) when their origin was Portland.  Gayot Fow notes [in his response](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77241/what-are-the-visa-rules-for-us-speakers-at-uk-conferences-who-may-be-getting-p/77246#77246):

> **The removal**
>
> She was served an IS82, which is the form they use when someone does not qualify for leave-to-enter AND their behaviour is inappropriate. It gives them the option, but not the obligation, to have her placed on the Home Secretary's exclusion list (that's a bad thing). ***They removed her to NYC instead of her base on the USA's west coast. They didn't have to do that, there are flights out to the west coast all the time, but that was just icing on the cake. Minimal compliance***.

Emphasis mine.

I cannot find anything in the UK rules which have changed to require removal to a destination which suits the traveller better - removing them to a port of entry they will be accepted at is good enough for UK immigration.

Comment: The UK is not in the EU, so this answer doesn't really apply.

Comment: @00 the UK was in the EU at the time of the above, so it may very well apply and its a good indication that there is no EU requirement to remove the traveller to somewhere which suits them.

Comment: @00 plus the UK still follows the bulk of EU rules and regulations up to the end of this year.

Comment: @00 And I'll add that UK immigration staff is apt to behave in the same way...if they're annoyed at the traveler's behavior, things will Not Go Well for the traveler.

Comment: You should add some of your comments to your answer, to clarify why your answer is relevant, even if the UK is not in the EU.

Comment: They followed the EU rules that were valid in the U.K. at that time, so you can expect any EU country to behave the same. I wonder what you have to do to get marked with “inappropriate behaviour”.

Comment: @gnasher729 Perhaps he slurped his tea. Or pronounced it A-loom-inum.

Comment: Given that this answer is based on EU rules at a particular date and which may have changed since, the relevant date should probably be included, even if the UK/EU relationship is not relevant.

Comment: EU rules don't actually specify how immigration should work in this level of detail? There's *Schengen*, which is a subset of the EU, and there are ECHR rulings on specific cases (also not part of EU law), but I'm not aware of any EU treaty law or Directives specifying the detail of immigration process?

Comment: Wow, thanks for that, a great link on what not to do at immigration.  Represented it as a speaker engagement when really it was teaching a multi-day class for significant money, and turns out, UKVI knows how to use Google.

Answer (score 12):

First, it’s unlikely to happen because the airline will try not to let people on board that would be denied entry.

Second, the airline taking you say from London to Berlin where you are rejected, would be fined, and would have to take you back to London. Because that’s the place where you would have been if they hadn’t let you on the flight.

The airline has to fly you back at their expense, but will try to make you pay for it. Your nationality is unlikely to make a difference.

(“At their expense” means immigration won’t pay for the flight, and if your pockets are empty they still have to fly you. Once you are back, they will try to make you pay. And you owe them the money. But if you have no money, you can’t pay them).

Comment: "at their expense" - citation?

Comment: @Mazura Look at this answer that quotes: [ICAO Annex 9 chapter 5 covers removal. Entries 5.10 and 5.11](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/51347/95267)

Comment: @Mazura The rule that the airline will pay for deportation is laid down in a contract between the host country and the airline, and "at their expense" means that immigration won't pay for the flight back. A contract cannot impose any obligations on a third party. The airline, however, has a contract with the traveller, which include their Terms Of Carriage, and these usually impose an obligation on the traveller to reimburse the airline for all cost incurred by them due to unsuccessful immigration.

Comment: @Alexander So then do they expect the passenger to pay for not only the ticket but the fees that the airline had to pay? I read that the fees can be thousands of dollars.

Comment: @JamesSmith I cannot answer this for all airlines, of course, but the last Conditions of Carriage I read was that of [Tiger Air Australia](https://tigerair.com.au/support/conditions-of-carriage) and they state that "You agree to pay the applicable fare, penalties and fines whenever we, on order of any government or immigration authority, are required to return you to your point of origin or elsewhere, owing to your inadmissibility into any country, state or territory on any part of your journey".

Comment: Airlines will block people who don't meet the basic requirements of having either a visa or a passport from a country that can enter without a visa but at least in the UK people still get refused entry for failing to convince the immigration officer that they are legitimate visitors.

Comment: @Alexander The airline is not penalized or fined unless the passenger is denied entry for something that the airline should have caught. The airline can only catch problems with the passenger's passport and ticket because that is all that they check. They don't check other things that only the immigration officer could check.

Answer (score 11):

This is an old story but it may still be helpful.  1983 so it was not actually the EU but the EEC.  Some things have changed but I think that the ones relevant to this question has not.

I had been backpacking around Asia on a very low budget.  When my money started to get low, I bought the cheapest ticket to home or close to home that I could.  This was on Biman Airways from Dhaka Bangladesh to Amsterdam.  My plan was to hitch from Amsterdam to my sister in Copenhagen.  On arrival in Amsterdam, I was stopped and questioned at immigration.  I was asked how much money I had and I was only able to produce one $20 traveller's cheque and six $1 notes.  Even at the time, this was not an impressive amount of money.  I tried to argue that since I was Irish, I even had the right to work in the Netherlands.  The officer replied that I had not stated that my intent was to work so he did not have to admit me.  I claimed that I could get to England where I lived (it was possible) but he said that since I was Irish, he could not be sure that the UK would admit me.  If I could not afford to fly to Ireland then he would instruct the airline to return me to Dhaka.  Obviously, that was not desirable.  My only other choice was to be detained while I arranged for some money to be sent to me.  I was put in a cell for three days until I was able to arrange for money to be sent to me.  That was not as easy then as it would be today.  Once I had enough money to afford a ticket to Dublin, I was permitted to enter the Netherlands.  Fortunately, I was not forced to buy a ticket to Ireland.  I managed to buy a bus / boat ticket to Ipswich in the UK and it actually cost slightly less than $26.  So, I could have got home with my original budget but I would have been very hungry as there was little change from my $26.  A final insult was that I was charged for meals and accommodation while I was detained.

In my cell were two other Irishmen.  Maybe it was a special Don't let the Irish in day.  They were returned to Dublin.

Comment: How does a story from 37 years ago, concerning a completely different political regime and preceding a number of regulations specific to rejected entries, help to answer the question at all?

Comment: Wow! What an impressive story

Comment: @Nij I thought that it might give the OP an idea of what might happen.  I'll let him decide whether it is useful.

Comment: I also feel it is a useful illustration of the situation, and too long for a comment. Not a non-answer in my view.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks. I hoped that it could be useful.  A key point is that they could have sent me back to Dhaka which was probably not good for anyone, certainly not me.  London and Dublin were nearer but they could not insist that the airline take me to either of those.  So, that was a strong incentive for me to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes. Thousands of dollars.

First, the airline won't let you board unless your papers are in order (or they pay a harsh fine). But even then, you can botch the entry interview or have a visa problem the airline can't foresee (the airline isn't fined in that case).

At that point, the airline is responsible to the State to remove you from the country (that agreement is not particular as to where).  And that can blow up in their face if they remove you to a country *that also refuses you*.  So they try to send you to a place you won't be or can't be refused, e.g. your country of citizenship unless you have right-of-residency somewhere else.

For this removal trip, the airline is responsible to the State to *make it happen*.  **However you are responsible to the airline for the cost of it!**

And  yes, they can send you wherever they please within your country. Least, they're not going to bump a paying passenger simply to get you to an internal destination of choice.  In other cases, the destination is impossible: If your itinerary started in South Bend, Indiana, there are no flights from LHR to South Bend for instance.

Many of us who travel rely on bargain fares which are only a small percentage of "full card rate, retail" fares.  Naturally since this is last-minute and compulsory travel, you are likely to be stuck paying full card rate for that ticket.  They gotcha!

I suspect if you already had a ticket in your pocket that would suffice for the refusal flight, and was timed to be suitable, they would just let you use that, especially if it was with the same (responsible) airline.